# Perl regexps not matching string with leading zeros / incorrectly escaped numerals with leading zeros on command line in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

*I have updated this question, as in the original question the issue I was chasing turned out to be an alltogether different bug (not interesting in this context). But the second order mistake I did in testing is something others may run into and produced an answer with a very interesting insight, so I'll leave this here as a question.*

I was trying to track down an issue with regular expressions seemingly not matching due to leading zeros. I found that all of the following regexp didn't match in my command line tests:

```
"005630" =~ /^0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)$/
"005630" =~ /0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/  
"005630" =~ /56(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/
"005630" =~ /..56(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/
"005630" =~ /..5630/
"005630" =~ /005630/
"005630" =~ /^005630$/
"005630" =~ /5630/
"005630" =~ /(0)*5630/
"005630" =~ /5630/g
"005630" =~ m/5630/g
```

This did match:

```
"x005630" =~ /0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/
```

similar for others, i.e. once I added a leading letter, it works.

The test code was (tested with Cygwin Perl v5.10.1 on a Cygwin bash):

```
perl -e "print ( "005630" =~ /0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/)"   # does not display a true value
perl -e "print ( "x005630" =~ /0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/)"  # displays a true value
```

The quoting here is obviously a mistake (can't use unescaped `"` in a string quoted with `"`). But I still didn't understand why the second line works despite incorrect quoting.

Note: This could also occur in other situations without regular expressions.

Comment: All of those work fine. Please copy and paste some code that shows the symptoms you describe

Comment: They *all* work for me too (v5.12.4). How are you using these matches? Can you show actual code, including some context? Also, try this regex: `/^0056(?:[12][015]|3[01])$/`.

Comment: Works fine for me on Perl 5.10.0 and 5.16.2: `perl -le 'print "ok" if "005630" =~ /^0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)$/' ; $ ok` That line was copy&pasted from your question. So maybe you're running into a bug in Perl 5.10.1?

Comment: thanks for all your input everyone so far. I have found a second degree test mistake (see above). amon's `perl -e 'print ( "005630" =~ /^0056(?:[12][015]|3[01])$/)'` works.

Comment: You may have issues with character interpretation when you use `$_` as the regex pattern. Does the pattern have anything that may be interpreted as special regex characters?  Use `\Q$_\E` to match the literal content of `$_`.  Or better yet, if you are doing an exact match, as it appears, just compare with `eq` instead of a regex.

Comment: Thanks dan1111, I do want to use the initial pattern `0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)` in $_ (and I would have written the code a bit different anyway, but it is not mine, I just wanted to see why my configuration isn't working). But I think I may have some completely different issue here, seeing that I tested wrong initially.

Comment: You commented out the assignment back to `$alarmConf{'codes'}{$log{"code"}}`. Could that have made the difference?

Comment: Thanks Mikko L, that is an interesting point and the line actually seems pointless. I have update my test code to replicate and it doesn't seem to cause harm (will update original question in a moment).

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. After all I started to change the CGI script and eventually found this was an altogether different bug, which I fixed (and send back to the author). My test issues on the command line were misleading me to believe in the leading zero issue. Anyway I think cjms answer is quite interesting and I will once again update my question, so that it will hopefully help others in similar situations and this here will have some value to the community.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why given the commands

```
perl -e "print ( "005630" =~ /0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/)"
perl -e "print ( "x005630" =~ /0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/)"
```

only the second line prints a match is that Perl supports [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) [numeric literals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors).  As you figured out, your shell is eating the quotes, so you're actually executing the statements:

```
print ( 005630 =~ /0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/);
print ( x005630 =~ /0056(10|11|15|20|21|25|30|31)/);
```

Any numeric literal (an unquoted number) that begins with a zero that isn't immediately followed by a decimal point is treated as an octal number.

```
perl -e "print 005630 . ''"  # prints 2968
perl -e "print x005630 . ''" # prints x005630
```

(The `. ''` is needed here to ensure that the bareword is treated as a string.  The `=~` operator does that in your example.)

So the reason your regex doesn't match is that your string doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: pretty good explanation - it's tough embedding code in paragraphs

Comment: Thanks cjm! I should have really started with a test script in a file, when I started to look at this - shells are dangerous ;) Interesting with the octal numbers, it does ring a bell. Sounds like a dangerous feature to have leading zeros trigger that (I would prefer prefixes like 0x etc). Maybe the same thing is happening in the script I'm trying to debug, I will try to configure the octal value and see what happens.